# matlab: different instances start with the same random seed

Tags: matlab, random, cluster-computing, random-seed

Using MATLAB and trying to use a computer cluster to perform 100 repetitions of certain calculation with inherent stochastic nature. Each of those repetitions should include the same code, but with different random seed.
It seems that

```
rng('shuffle')
```

[recommended by documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-different.html) may not achieve this if all jobs start running at the same time (on different machines) as the seed used is an integer which seems to be initialized from time (it is monotonously increasing, seems like precision of 100th of a second.

The precision seems reasonable, but "collisions" are still very likely if running 100-1000 instances at the same time, thus corrupting the results statistical interpretation as independent.

Any way to avoid such collisions without manually giving each instance an "instance id" used as seed?

Comment: Don't seed from just the time.  Assign each machine a unique number and seed each machine's RNG with (time + number).  Spread the numbers well out, far enough apart that time in unlikely to catch up with the next number.

Comment: I agree, but how to actually do that with Matlab?  How can it access such per-machine unique number?

Comment: read my answer ... serialnumber or ProcessorId

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you choose for the seed, it can only take on a 32-bit value, even if it will initialize a generator with a bigger state, such as Mersenne Twister ('twister', 19937 bits).  There are certain issues with 32-bit seeds, as discussed in "[C++ Seeding Surprises](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html)" by M. O'Neill.  Presumably, the time-based seeds are likewise 32 bits long.  A short seed means that only a limited number of pseudorandom sequences can be generated.

It appears that `rng` doesn't support seeds longer than 32 bits. On the other hand, recent versions of MATLAB support [*random number streams*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-controlling-a-random-number-stream.html), which are designed, among other things, if you "want separate sources of randomness in a simulation".  For your purposes, choose a generator that supports multiple streams, such as `mrg32k3a`, and create random number streams as follows (see also ["Multiple Streams"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multiple-streams.html)):

```
[stream1, stream2]=RandStream.create('mrg32k3a','NumStreams',2)
```

Comment: You can add `'CellOutput',true` to the function call, then the output is a single cell array with all the streams. More convenient when generating 100 or 1000 streams as OP seems to need.

Answer (score 2):

I usually try to get some serial numbers from the machine or HDD, e.g.

```
dos('wmic bios get serialnumber')
```

or

```
dos('wmic cpu')
```

ProcessorId e.g. "BFEBFBFF000506E3" is another one that could be used and
be different across your cluster. Likely multicores thus use NumberOfCores
to split and have different seeds, maybe.

Comment: Combine this with time in some way to get unique seeds even when a compute node is used repeatedly for job sub-steps.