# Is it possibile to create a seed not based on time in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am running a matlab code on a cluster and I am running around 100 simulations at the same time. However, I noticed that although I am using the `rng('shuffle')` command, I sometimes get the same seed for a couple of simulations probabily because the cluster is submitting some simulations at the same exact time.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matlab: different instances start with the same random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890097/matlab-different-instances-start-with-the-same-random-seed)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a set of random numbers before the cluster job submission, in a single thread with a single call to any random number generator. Then, use those numbers as seed for the cluster jobs, either via passing them as argument or reading from file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I tell matlab to sue those numbers as a seed?

Comment: So I am gonna generate this stream in the code and then call one of the random numbers with rng(number)?

Comment: Yes, generate some numbers before you run the cluster job, and then use each of those numbers as seed for the number generator. If the numbers are different, the random numbers that will come out of those seeds will be different. Normally, MATLAB picks that number for you (by e.g. reading the timer) but in here, you are forcing it, to make sure its different

Comment: I have generated a vector r1 of 1000 random numbers. How do I pass a different random number of this vector to rng?

Comment: Cause then I would have to create a random number between 1 and 1000 that passes the number to rng and I would run into the same problem

Comment: Only you have your code, I can not tell you how to modify your code unless you show it. But basically, the same way you pass any variable to any thread in the cluster job you have. But of course, you want to pass each job a different number. This should not be too hard, but may be dependent on your cluster and how you have your code set up. A bit off topic for this question, considering you shared zero code.

Comment: In my cluster I am just subitting my code using a command the repeats this n times

Comment: That command can have arguments, and the matlab code you use also can have input arguments. Nothing that can't be easily done.